# Passing a function as a parameter to another function

Tags: php

This code works and there may be better methods to achieve the thing,but my questions are ,

***Is there any specific term for passing like this ?*** (as with anonymous functions ),
  ***is this an acceptable practice ? ,***

***is it against standards ?***

```
<?php
// suppose the only way i can retrieve the content is by using this function 
//like  wordpress equivalent of the_content()
function mycontent()
{
    $Original_content="oldcontent";
    return $Original_content;
}

//instead of ---> echo $Original_content."facebook,twitter code";
//if i define a new function
function social_share($content)
{
    $added_social=$content;
    $added_social.=" +  facebook,twitter code...";
    echo $added_social;
}

//function call
social_share(mycontent());
?>
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have some sort of very basic ... controller maybe, but it is quite the minimum. Work it from there and build on it. See if it works and then maybe as a bonus check if it scales.

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly fine, except that you are not actually passing "one function as a parameter to another function". social_share(mycontent()) first evaluates mycontent(), the result of that function is passed to social share, not the function mycontent. But that's just terminology, the code itself is fine.
And i don't think there's a special term for what you're doing.
It's just shorthand for: $tmp = mycontent(); social_share($tmp); Your code is preferable, since you're not creating useless variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a function. You're passing the result of one function call directly to another as an argument. 'passing a function' implies that the 'parent' function will be calling the 'child' function at some point. IN this case, social_share does NOT invoke mycontent() at all - that's done long before social_share even executes.

That being said, if you had something like this:

```
function my_echo($arg) {
   print($arg);
}

function social_share($somearg, $func_to_invoke) {
    $$func_to_invoke($somearg);
}

social_share('hello', 'my_echo');
```

then you would be invoking one function from another by passing it as an argument. In this case, you'd get "hello" printed out by your little custom `my_echo` function, without ever having written `my_echo('hello');`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with this at all. This is a lot like object oriented approaches in fact. You can create a class that has these methods and use them to pass other properties to other objects and classes and etc. It's good practice in my opinion.